# Error when using PutInfluxDatabaseRecord in Apache Ni-Fi due to time stamp

Tags: timestamp, apache-nifi, influxdb

I have created a Apache Ni-Fi flow [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkqg0.png) to fetch a simple table from a MySQL server and copy it into InfluxDB after some data transformation.

I use the PutInfluxDataRecord processor to convert the data from AVRO format into In-Line protocol and to insert the data into Influx (by using StandardInfluxDatabaseService 1.15.0-SNAPSHOT controller service).

In the Avro Reader 1.15.2 controller service I have selected the option Schema Access Strategy: Use Embedded Avro Schema.

In the properties of the PutInfluxDataRecord processor I set the value of the Timestamp field property as "time_stamp", which is the name of the field containing the timestamp in the input flow of the processor.

When running the flow, I get the following error:

> PutInfluxDatabaseRecord[id=6d21f785-017e-1000-e0da-0528ab2de725]
> Failed procession flow file f0c553ef-7a4b-414c-bd9f-be2c6b7bf4f5 due
> to For input string: "2021-01-11 09:00:00.0":
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2021-01-11
> 09:00:00.0"

In the property tab of the PutInfluxDatabaseRecord processor, in the help text of the Timestamp field property it says that the supported types are: java.util.Date, java.lang.Number and java.lang.String.

Any hints how I could fix this?

Thanks,

Bernardo

[Apache Ni-Fi flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkqg0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the settings in the QueryDatabaseTable processor that I used to fetch the data from the MySQL server. I did the following change:

Use Avro Logical Types: true

This prevented Ni-Fi to set time_stamp as a string.