# Error about schema name when using UpdateRecord with AvroReader and AvroRecordSetWriter in Apache Ni-Fi

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I have created an Apache Ni-Fi pipeline to fetch data from a MySQL server into InfluxDB.

The first processor is QueryDatabaseTable which uses DBCPConnectioPool to connect to the MySQL database.

This processor does some data transformations (column drop, column rename and data filtering (dropping out certain rows)).

The content of the output of this processor is the following one:

```
[ {
  "original_id" : 1,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 09:00:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 3,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 2,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 09:10:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : null,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 3,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 3,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 09:20:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : null,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 3,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 4,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 09:30:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : null,
  "metric" : 3,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 5,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 10:00:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 18,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 6,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 10:10:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 20,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 7,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 10:20:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 7,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 8,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 10:30:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 4,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 9,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 10:40:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 8,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 10,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 11:00:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 150,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 5.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 11,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 12:00:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 5,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 0.0
}, {
  "original_id" : 12,
  "time_stamp" : "2021-01-11 12:10:00.0",
  "apartment_id" : 69,
  "room_id" : 77,
  "sensor_id" : 8,
  "metric" : 5,
  "valueSum" : 25.0,
  "valueDiv" : 0.0
} ]
```

The next processor is UpdateRecord, which I use to do some further data transformation (replace NULL values with zeros in some columns and adding a new column).

Those are the relevant configurations in the processor for the above mentioned data transformations:

- /apartment_id: ${field.value:replaceNull(0)}
- /room_id: ${field.value:replaceNull(0)}
- /sensor_id: ${field.value:replaceNull(0)}
- /original_db: 1

As a record reader I use AvroReader controller service with the following configurations:

- Schema Access Strategy: Use 'Schema Name' Property
- Schema Registry: AvroSchemaRegistry
- Schema Name: $(firstschema)

As a record writer I use AvroRecordSetWriter controller service with the following configurations:

- Schema Write Strategy: Embeded Avro Schema
- Schema Access Strategy: Use 'Schema Name' Property
- Schema Registry: AvroSchemaRegistry
- Schema Name: $(secondschema)

In the AvroSchemaRegistry I have configured the following properties:

firstschema

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "mysql.influx",
     "name": "firstschema",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "time_stamp", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "apartment_id", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "room_id", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "sensor_id", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "metric", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "original_id", "type": "long" },
       { "name": "valueSum", "type": "double" },
       { "name": "valueDiv", "type": "double" }
     ]
}
```

secondschema

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "mysql.influx",
     "name": "secondschema",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "time_stamp", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "apartment_id", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "room_id", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "sensor_id", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "metric", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "original_db", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "original_id", "type": "long" },
       { "name": "valueSum", "type": "double" },
       { "name": "valueDiv", "type": "double" }
     ]
}
```

When running the flow I get the following error on the second processor:

> UpdateRecord[id=017e1004-c2d8-14cf-6d9d-374a1143abb0]  Failed to
> process
> StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=c52d4145-ba5f-4f51-8f90-5313f461dbd8,claim=StandardContentClaim
> [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1644394716708-2,
> container=default, section=2], offset=850134,
> length=1143],offset=0,name=c52d4145-ba5f-4f51-8f90-5313f461dbd8,size=1143];
> will route to failure: ${firstschema} did not provide appropriate
> Schema Name

I obtain the same result when I change the setting in the AvroRecordSetWriter controller service as follows:

- Schema Write Strategy: Set 'schema.name' Attribute

Also, I obtain the same result if I make the following changes to AvroReader configuration:

- Schema Name: $(mysql.influx.firstschema)

The reason why I am not using the option Schema Access Strategy: Use Embedded Avro Schema in AvroReader controller service is that by doing so I get an issue with the format of the time stamp later on in the flow, as described in this other post:

[Error when using PutInfluxDatabaseRecord in Apache Ni-Fi due to time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047227/error-when-using-putinfluxdatabaserecord-in-apache-ni-fi-due-to-time-stamp)

I am using Apache Ni-Fi 1.15.2

Any hint what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Bernardo

Comment: This might be helpful - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Am-I-Configuring-NiFi-s-AvroSchemaRegistry-Correctly/td-p/210783

Comment: Is "firstschema" the name of the schema in the AvroSchemaRegistry service? (i.e. the name of the property you added where the value is the schema)

Comment: If so then in the reader and writer, you should be using ${...} to reference the names, just put the actual names. The ${...} is expression language which is saying to evaluate the expression and use the returned value, so unless you have a flow file attribute name firstschema that then evaluates to firstschema, it is not going to work.